# Rate of increase of depth of water pumped into conical vessel

Tags: calculus

I cannot get the answer shown in my text book for this problem:

Water runs into a conical vessel fixed with its vertex downwards at the rate of $3 \pi$ cubic cm per second, filling the vessel to a depth of 15 cm in a time of one minute. Find the rate at which the depth of water in the vessel is increasing when the water has been running for 7.5 seconds.

I have said let V = volume, h = depth of water and r = radius of surface of water:

$V = \frac{\pi r^2h}{3}$

When $V = 180 \pi, h = 15$ so $180 \pi = \frac{\pi r^2h}{3}, 540 = r^2h = 15r^2$ so $r = 6$

Therefore the ratio of r to h is 6:15 = 2:5, so $r = \frac{2}{5}h$

So $V = (\frac{2}{5}h)^2\frac{\pi h}{3} = \frac{4h^3\pi}{75}$ and $\frac{dV}{dh} = \frac{12h^2\pi}{75}$

Now to find $\frac{dh}{dt}$

After 7.5 seconds $V = 7.5$ x $3\pi = 22.5$

I need to find h, so:

$22.5 = \frac{4 \pi h^3}{75}$ so $h = 5.12$

$\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{dV}{dh}.\frac{dh}{dt}$

$\frac{dV}{dt} = 3\pi, \frac{dV}{dh} = \frac{12h^2\pi}{75} $

but when I substitute these values, plus that for h, I do not get the correct answer, which is $\frac{1}{3}$ cm per sec.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Cone is empty at start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You method of solution is correct, but you have miscalculated the value of $h$ when $t=7.5$.  The correct calculation is

$h^3=\frac{22.5*75}{4}$ so $h=7.5$ and it follows that $\frac{dV}{dt}=1/3$.

Comment: Thanks very much Andrew